# Does value assignment increase, or decrease, performance or does it do nothing?

Tags: c#, arrays

Never thought about this but, does value assignment, e.g. `int a = 100`, increase performance or does it decrease performance or does it do nothing at all? Now, `int a = 100` isn't what i really had in mind but, lets say you have something like this:

```
 string[] a = new string[] { null, "a", "b", "", null }

 string[] b = new string[] { null, "a", "b", "", null }

 bool result = Equals(a, b);


 public static bool Equals<T>(T[] array, T[] buffer)
 {
      if (array != null && array.Length > 0 && buffer != null && buffer.Length > 0 && array.Length == buffer.Length)
      {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      {
           if (array[i] == null && buffer[i] != null)
           {
                break;
           }
           else if (array[i] != null && buffer[i] == null)
           {
                break;
           }
           else if (array[i].ToString() != buffer[i].ToString())
           {
                break;
           }
           else if (i == array.Length - 1)
           {
                return true;
           }
      }
      }
      return false;
 }
```

would doing `T cell = array[i]` & `T cell2 = buffer[i]` (`in the Equals method`) and then comparing `cell` to `cell2` increase performance and speed or would it decrease performance and speed or would it change nothing?

Comment: If it would have impact, it would be picked up by the optimizer.

Comment: You are performing 6 dereferencing operations instead of just two in each loop. Since you *always* use the same value, there's no need to repeat `array[i]` everywhere.

Comment: IMHO these kinds of "micro optimizations" are often uneccessary and tend to just overcomplicate things. Have you encountered a perfomance problem, and are you sure that code like the above is the root source of that problem? Otherwise I think you might just be overthinking this ;)

Comment: BTW what you try to do here is probably already provided by [SequenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This code will cause *serious* performance issues due to the calls to `ToString()`. For any type *except* a string this will create a new temporary string that will have to be garbage-collected. If the method is only meant to work on strings, there's no reason to make it generic

Comment: Also 90% of the code is redundant

Comment: It's a example xD

Comment: What if you try to compare arrays of different lengths? This method will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled i am well aware, it's just a example, obviously, first you would see if `array.Length == buffer.Length` and then only do the compares.

Comment: @Lissss001 Well I have no way of knowing what you are aware of and what you are not aware of... I can only refer to the code you've posted.

Comment: I think the answer is, disregarding optimizations (for which the CLR does aggressively). every comparison, every assignment, every && every iteration, is one or mote CPU instruction. All things being equal, the less you do the better, however the truth be known, the types of things you do matter a lot more. So it a big depends question

Comment: If your interested (and for a riotous night of fun), you could download, BenchmarkDotNet, and time various iterations of your method. you will get a good/better feel for what is more performant and what isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory call for an array element `array[i]` includes addition of the element index to the base address in assembler code, but that costs essentially nothing, it is as easy as calling variable `cell`. So, in your example, introducing variables `T cell = array[i]` & `T cell2 = buffer[i]` won't influence performance.

But in some other cases, when your expression requires more time to evaluate, it is reasonable to introduce a variable and save value once at the beginning.